# Missing Controller in CakePHP 1.3.21

Tags: php, controller, cakephp-1.3

I'm just new in using CakePHP Framework. so I'm trying to display a view but it says missing controller. here is my code

```
UsersController.php

    class UsersController extends AppController{

    var $name = 'Users';

    function hello_cake(){

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The error message Cake gives you should also indicate where it's looking for the controller. I would double check that the file you have is in the right place, that's likely your problem. If not, ensure your URL is correct - in this case it should be something like http://localhost/users/hello_cake

If you're still having issues please provide more detail, like the URL you're hitting, the full error message displayed, etc., and I'll try to provide more assistance.